# PSBT signing safety checks

Tags: bip174-psbt

I'm working on a multisignature cold storage wallet that adds several features to the Glacier Protocol wallet, namely PSBT support through bitcoin-cli's RPC interface. The wallet intentionally uses a very restricted portion of the PSBT standard in order to make the code as short and easily auditable as possible. I define a function [validate_psbt()](https://github.com/hodlwave/proof-wallet/blob/4b2c81966d15fee6edc2f3c65e480fdde224f813/glacierscript.py#L500) that aims to exhaustively check whether or not a PSBT is safe for a user to inspect and sign:

- A user inputs the `M` & `N` policy, `1 xprv` and `N xpubs` at the start of the signing process
- The only valid wallet addresses are `wsh(sortedmulti(M, [xfp_1]xpub_1/change/idx, [xfp_2]xpub_2/change/idx, ... , [fp_n]xpub_n/change/idx))` where change in {0, 1} (i.e. derivation paths for each xpub must be the same). Only using segwit addresses should prevent signing inputs that overspend fees for example.
- The wallet only allows users to sign transactions that spend their own inputs.
- To be considered change, sufficient metadata must be provided for output at `idx`, which the wallet uses to calculate an address cross-checked against the address in the PSBT's `tx.vout[idx]` field.

Are there any missing validations that need to be performed in this process to ensure that a maliciously created PSBT doesn't pass the safety check, letting a user unknowingly sign away / lock up her bitcoins?